# Grab image from web, save it in sql database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to grab an image from the web, and add it to my database.

```
String lsResponse = string.Empty;

using (HttpWebResponse lxResponse = (HttpWebResponse)req1.GetResponse())
{
   using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(lxResponse.GetResponseStream()))
   {
      Byte[] lnByte = reader.ReadBytes(1 * 1024 * 1024 * 10);

      using (FileStream lxFS = new FileStream(id + ".png", FileMode.Create))
      {
         lxFS.Write(lnByte, 0, lnByte.Length);
```

My SQL Server datatype is `Varbinary(MAX)`. Tried with different types (image,...) did not work.

Put it into database.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO PlayersDB (id) ) VALUES (@id);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", lnByte);
```

I keep getting an error:

> Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

So, my program sees my `lnByte` not as binary?

Answer (score 1):

First be sure about the data type is correct.I don't know much about SQL server but i've encountered similar problem in MySql. I changed the data type to Blob and it worked

Answer (score 1):

We use blobs for storing images within a sql db at my workplace. I'm not particularly experienced with it myself, but here are some Technet resources that can explain it better than I can.

[Binary Large Object (Blob) Data (SQL Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895234.aspx)

[FILESTREAM (SQL Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx)